# How to override env file on newman run?

Tags: testing, environment-variables, postman, newman

How to rewrite variables in Newman? I have a file with my environment variables that are rewritten after a request is executed, everything works in Postman (RUN FOLDER), but in Newman all tests crash. Many of my variables do not have initial values, they only acquire them when a test passes. For example there is a POST request that adds a user, the body of the response will return to me:

```json
{
    "id": null,
    "result": {
        "id": "c9497eb1-e4ea-47f0-a00e-a46cf8ef07a7"
    },
    "success": true
}
```

I take the value of the ID, and override the variable with the following command:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set('newUserId', jsonData.result.id);
```

When running Newman, everything crashes. Please help, if you would be so kind.

What key should I use when starting Newman? Or how to achieve positive results in NEWMAN to be like in Postman, is there such an option for processing variables?

Many tests drops when I use env value in URL path, like
`https://some-url/check/{createdUserId}`.

Comment: How about starting with reading the instructions for Newman in the Postman Learning Centre, or the GitHub repository.  Both explain how to use environment files in your command line.   You then might want to include what command line you are currently executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export also environment variable too.
The 'newman' running no problem if using exported `environment variable`

#### How to export environment variable.

##### Select 'environment quick look' - right/top icon in Postman

[image]

##### Select 'edit' menu

[image]

##### Select See more action (...)

[image]

##### Run newman with exported environment.json

```
newman run my.postman_collection.json  -e my.postman_environment.json
```

Demo

#1 running a local API server for adding user and getting user

#2 postman call

#3 running collection

#4 newman running

##### #1 running a local API server

Save as 'server'js'

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const users = {}; // Memory storage for user data

// API 1: Create(Add) user by POST
app.post('/createUser', (req, res) => {
  const { first_name, last_name, email } = req.body;
  const userId = uuid.v4(); // Generate a new UUID for the user

  users[userId] = { first_name, last_name, email }; // Store user data in memory

  res.status(201).json({
    id: null, // You can set this to any specific value if needed
    result: {
      id: userId,
    },
    success: true,
  });
});

// API 2: Get user by GET
app.get('/getUser/:user_id', (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.user_id;
  const user = users[userId];

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
  }

  res.json({
    first_name: user.first_name,
    last_name: user.last_name,
    email: user.email,
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install express cors uuid
```

##### Running server

```
node server.js
```

[image]

##### #2 postman call

Create User 1 and get User 1, checked user information (name and email)
Key is using `user-id` environment variable for POST (Adding)/GET(Getting) user pair.

If not matched Adding user/ Getting user, something wrong.

[image]

##### POST returned

```
{
    "id": null,
    "result": {
        "id": {"uuid"}
    },
    "success": true
}
```

##### GET user

```
http://localhost:3000/getUser/{{user-id : uuid}}
```

Response

```
{"first_name":"Steve","last_name":"Jobs","email":"steve_jobs@example.com"}
```

It can confirmed created user and get user is same or not by calling GET with `uuid`

This format

##### Create User1

`Tests` tab for adding user

POST call

```
http://localhost:3000/createUser
```

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("user-id", jsonData.result.id);
console.log(pm.environment.get("user-id"));
```

[image]

Body

```
{
    "first_name": "Steve", 
    "last_name":"Jobs", 
    "email": "steve_jobs@example.com"
}
```

[image]

##### Get User1

`Tests` tab for adding user

GET call

```
http://localhost:3000/getUser/{{user-id}}
```

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData);

pm.expect(jsonData.first_name).to.eql("Steve");
pm.expect(jsonData.last_name).to.eql("Jobs");
pm.expect(jsonData.email).to.eql("steve_jobs@example.com");
```

[image]

[image]

Add user 2 with different user information

[image]

##### #3 running collection on Postman

[image]

##### #4 `newman` running on terminal

```bash
newman run 1-1-demo.postman_collection.json  -e demo.postman_environment.json
```

[image]

Comment: God Bless You! I read in the official documentation how to work with variables in newman. In conjunction with your answer, I got the necessary knowledge, now all tests pass as they should! Thank you very much for making the world a little better!

Comment: Good to hear, you got it. Can you accept my answer? It make me happy.